# Regex to disable URL's, but enable only one

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all links in a string, but keep the URL of my website in the string.

This is what I've tried so far:

example.com is my domain.

```
(https?:\/\/)?((?:(\w+-)*\w+)\.)+(?:[a-z]{2})(\/?\w?-?=?_?\??&?)+[\.]?(?!example.com)
```

Sample inputs include:

```
http://website.com
https://www.website.com
http://www.website.com
string http://website.com
http://website.com string
string example.com
string www.example.com
string http://website.com www.example.com
www.website.com example.com
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Sample input and output please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this much more simply; right now, your regex contains a lot of groups and conditions that don't relate to your question as written.

## Simple Version (Requiring a Protocol)

Here's a regex that does what you want, assuming links contain protocols (`http` or `https`):

```
/https?:\/\/(?!(www\.)?example\.com)\S+\s*/gi
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wEyFHD/1)

This looks for `http`, optionally `s`, and `://`, not followed by `www.example.com` or `example.com`, then a bunch of non-whitespace characters (`\S+`) and any trailing whitespace (`\s*`). Just replace any matches with an empty string.

Sample PHP code ([3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/TRWDg)):

```
$re = '/https?:\/\/(?!(www\.)?example\.com)\S+\s*/i';
$str = 'http://foo.com
https://foo.com/bar/baz/?blah=boo&bah=humbug#something
http://google.com/
http://example.com
http://example.com/
https://example.com
https://example.com/
https://example.com/bar/baz/?blah=boo&bah=humbug#something';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Output:

```
The result of the substitution is http://example.com
http://example.com/
https://example.com
https://example.com/
https://example.com/bar/baz/?blah=boo&bah=humbug#something
```

## More Complex Version (Not Requiring a Protocol)

If you want to strip out even things like `foo.com` (no protocol), which are not really "links," you have to get a bit more creative:

```
/https?:\/\/(?!(www\.)?example\.com)\S+\s*|(?!(www\.)?example.com)\b\w+\.[a-z]{2,}[\/?&=#\S]+\s*/gi
```

Here's a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VUkpva/2) and an [3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/fgCg3). The first part of this is the same as before, but contains an alternative clause:

```
(?!(www\.)?example.com)\b\w+\.[a-z]{2,}[\/?&=#\S]+\s*
```

This says to ignore what follows if it starts with either `www.example.com` or `example.com`. It then tries to match a word boundary (`\b`), a string of "word" characters (`\w+`), a period (`\.`), two or more letters (`[a-z]{2,}`), any additional characters that could follow the domain name (`[\/?&=#\S]+`), and any trailing whitespace (`\s*`).

Comment: This works, but how do I also catch links without http or https? or even without 'www'?

Comment: @Nedas I didn't realize based on your initial question that you were trying to catch "links" without protocols. I have edited my answer to show you how to do that. It works with or without the "www". Please note: real domain name validation is much more complex, and, in certain contexts, links can validly contain whitespace. My solution doesn't account for really odd edge cases involving, for example, international domains (non-Latin character sets), but it will handle 99.99% of URLs with no problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help!